# How to read client chat logs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm a new to Minecraft (Java edition). I have tried to make a parser (separate a message to sender, receiver, message) for CHAT history that is saved in ***%appdata%/.minecraft/logs/latest.log***. So, I understand for all conversations in Minecraft that line will start with prefix ***[CHAT]***, but I have noticed that the syntax in each Minecraft server can be different. For example,

**1st server**: [score] [sender] [receiver] [message]

**2nd server**: [sender] [receiver] [message]

**Examples:**

1. **zero.minr.org** -  [15:48:00] [Render thread/INFO]: [CHAT] User1: user2 hello, how are you
2. **brawl.com** - [15:42:09] [Render thread/INFO]: [CHAT] 4  user1 » user2 HOW are you?

Does some [programmatic] way to understand syntax or pattern of messages for each server exist? From each example, I need to extract who sent a message, who got a message (all or some tagged user), what was sent.

Maybe there might be another way to get Minecraft chat history on my computer?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us a real example (Taken out of the txt)? I have done this in the past and didn't have this problem.

Comment: The differences between servers could be just the version of minecraft server that its running or the mods in place. So first thing you would have to do is to know what is the difference between the 2 servers and hingeing your code on that (if its version A, assume the messages are build in the A way, and if its version B, assume the messages are built in the B way.)

Comment: @Fredy31 does exist some way to get this mapping in advance for each server (server -> format)? From logs?

Comment: I do not know Minecraft logs in particular, but usually logs should be the same all the time. So something is changing the logs in your second server. Now just to figure out what is making that change. A computer doesn't just decide 'meh, this time i'll do B-A-C instead of A-B-C'. A computer read instructions and does them as is.

Comment: I just saw that you edited your question: Maybe the first example is a general chat, but the second is a whisper (private chat)?

Comment: @Fredy31 No, they can be in different format in each server. The second is a general chat on **brawl.com** server.

Comment: Another issue, I don't understand if it's possible to understand that the second work it's nickname of tagged user or it's part of message.

Comment: I don't know lots about MC servers, but if you tell me they both run the same MC version, with the same plugins, then it might be a config when you setup the server. As I said, a computer doesn't freely decide how it will write logs just for the hell of it. It applies what is asked by the program.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but how can I know these things if it's not my servers?